# Get e-mail from input form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

Trying to get this to work. I know that I need to get this up and running on a mailserver to get this to work, however, I should be able to get the error messages out. Since when I'm validating the code under the "success" and "error" function directly in the console it works and the message appears. However when I'm pressing the submit button it doesn't.

--html--

```
   <div class="row">
        <form id="contactForm-1" name="sentMessage" novalidate>
           <div class="form-group">
             <input class="form-control" id="email-1" type="email" placeholder="Your Email *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
             <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
           </div>
        </form>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <div id="success-1"></div>
           <button id="sendMessageButton-1" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit">Send Message</button>
        </div>
```

--JS--

```
 $(function() {

 $("#contactForm-1 input").jqBootstrapValidation({
   preventSubmit: true,
submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
  // additional error messages or events
},
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
  // get values from FORM
  var email = $("input#email-1").val();
  // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
  $this = $("#sendMessageButton-1");
  $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
  $.ajax({
    url: "././mail/contact_me_start.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      email: email
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
      // Success message
      $('#success-1').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
      $('#success-1 > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
        .append("</button>");
      $('#success-1 > .alert-success')
        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
      $('#success-1 > .alert-success')
        .append('</div>');
      //clear all fields
      $('#contactForm-1').trigger("reset");
    },
    error: function() {
      // Fail message
      $('#success-1').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
      $('#success-1 > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
        .append("</button>");
      $('#success-1 > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry, it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
      $('#success-1 > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
      //clear all fields
      $('#contactForm-1').trigger("reset");
    },
    complete: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
},
filter: function() {
  return $(this).is(":visible");
   },
  });

  $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
  });
 });
```

--PHP--

```
   <?php
   // Check for empty fields
   if(empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form: ";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: \n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: \n\nMessage:";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>
```

Comment: Put your submit button inside the <form> tags.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot. It works now, sometimes it hasn't to be harder than that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `submit` button inside the form to make it work.